# Does Reindex Document Library button in settings impact crawl schedule?

Tags: search, managed-property, crawl

If I go into Advanced Setting in my document library and click Reindex Document Library, this will flag the library as needing a full crawl, but will it expedite that?

I don't have access to the crawl schedule in SharePoint 2013.  I'm trying to get some managed properties crawled to map them.

Any solution other than calling IT and asking for a full crawl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not expedite it, it just flags the document library or site to have the crawler perform a full crawl on the next pass.

If you've set up Continuous Crawl, this should be fairly quick.

Comment: So if a Continuous Crawl hits it....  It will see it has been flagged and it will issue a full crawl, or must I wait until whenever the next full crawl is scheduled?  Thanks!

Comment: If a CC hits the site, it'll see the flag and perform a full crawl on that site or list, whichever you've flagged for a FC.